# Reactive Extensions : Frequency of event

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Lets say I have a class like
MyClass { string id, string eventType, datetime ts}

ts is the timestamp of the event and Id is on which I want to calculate frequency

I have a hot observable of MyClass , I want to calculate number of events  recvd per stringId in the last 30 seconds

If number of events is more than 5 , I raise another event of MyClass (with same Id, and eventType ="New" ) and if it falls down below 3 again , I need to update the previously raised event (with same Id, and eventType ="New" ).

I think I need to use sliding window, I have reached so far

```
public static IObservable<MyClass> CountFrequency(this IObservable<MyClass> source, TimeSpan withinPeriod, string marker)
{
    // var scheduler = new HistoricalScheduler();
    //  var driveSchedule = source.Subscribe(e => scheduler.AdvanceTo(e.Timestamp)); 
    return source.Window(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        .SelectMany(sl => sl)
        .GroupBy(a => a.id)
        .SelectMany(go => go
        .Aggregate(new MyClass(), (acc, evt) => CustomAggFrequency(acc, evt, marker))
        .Select(count => count)));
}
```

I am not able to understand

a) How to relate scheduler to the timestamp of the data not system time
b) How to code the logic of CustomAggFrequency

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Will this not work?  Your question is phrased such that it's hard to figure out what you want.

```
var span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
var shift = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
var query = source
    .Window(span, shift)
    .Select(window => window
        .GroupBy(item => item.id)
        .ToDictionary(g => x.Key, g => g.Count() / span.TotalSeconds));
```

This `query` will emit a dictionary every 5 seconds that maps each `id` to its frequency in hertz during the last 30 seconds. Its type is `IObservable<Dictionary<string, double>>`.

Comment: Hello, Instead of using timespan , how can I use the timestamp which is present in MyClass. The issue I am facing its taking time for the events to reach my reactive operator, and by the time system time is already advanced by 30 seconds , so I get only 1 event

Comment: @user3529980 I still don't understand.